# Do lambda expressions that appear in different definitions of a same entity produce the same closure type?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

In C++20 we can use lambda expressions in unevaluated contexts. Consider the following C++20 code:

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo {
  using T = decltype([]{});
};  // struct Foo

const std::type_info& getType() { return typeid(typename Foo::T); }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo {
  using T = decltype([]{});
};  // struct Foo

const std::type_info& getType();

const std::type_info& getTypeFromMain() { return typeid(typename Foo::T); }

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha 
            << (getType() == getTypeFromMain());
  return 0;
}
```

What should the program output under standard C++?

AFAIK, GCC and clang output `false`. They believe that all lambda expressions should produce distinct closure types and are "local" to translation units.

On the other hand, [[basic.def.odr] 13.10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#13.10) states that closure types introduced by corresponding lambda expressions in different definitions of the same entity within different translation units should be the same, and the program should output `true`. Are GCC and clang wrong on this?

Comment: A trivial point: `typename` doesn’t do anything here.

Comment: Well if @DavisHerring isn't even answering this one, then I dunno what hope the rest of us have. Sure seems like the ODR rule states that these should be the same, although that's probably not the actual intent (i.e. `#include`-ing the definition in multiple TUs).

Comment: Wording in the Standard not withstanding - I can't see how a compiler can generate the same type for a lambda in two different compilation units given each compilation unit is a distinct task.  The Standard requires (except in this case) that lambda's have  unique types and I don't see how this special case can be detected.

Comment: clang 15 prints `true`.

Comment: @RichardCritten What's the problem? Clang somehow manages, and gcc does detect that a lambda inside an inline function has the same type regardless of the TU. What's the difference in this case?

Comment: @n.m. I wasn't trying to imply this was either wrong or impossible.  It was was more along the lines of _"how can the compiler do that?"_  Given you have demonstrated it can be done, I can't visualise a mechanism.

Comment: @RichardCritten Look at the [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/8YbYvMeK5). It is rather transparent.

Comment: GCC and Clang print different results. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PqKsedsf6).

Comment: @n.m. clang 15 prints `true` only because it's numbering the lambdas. If you have the lambdas be different, then you _still_ get true: https://godbolt.org/z/Pr4Wr46r8 (although you could argue that now this is really is an odr violation, so `true` is fine)

Comment: @Barry Exactly, this is an ODR violation, nothing to argue here. GCC numbers the lambdas too, no difference here. The difference is in the `operator==` implementation.

Comment: @Barry Seems like clang numbers the closure types in the order that the closure types are referenced from within a typeid expression, and this can lead to apparently wrong results: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1jb16baEP)

Comment: Yes, gcc numbers the lambdas correctly but fails to compare the type_info object correctly. clang compares the type_info objects correctly but fails to number the lambdas correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, the closure type is the same in all translation units, and the compilers are still catching up to that.  The *mechanism* for doing so is generating (mangled) names for the closure type from its placement within the overall definition (by, say, counting them, as mentioned in the comments).  The *reason* in the standard that this works is somewhat subtle.

[basic.def.odr]/13.10 does not specify that the closure types are the same; it uses "shall" and so *requires* that they be the same (which, given the following, has an effect only in even more subtle cases).  It is /14 that has that effect: "the behavior is as if there is a **single** entity with a single definition", which necessarily produces a single closure type.  Even then, it's not proper to say that the lambda expressions "produce the same closure type": rather, only **one** of the closure types produced has any relevance to the program as a whole.

Note that without provisions like this, simple functions like

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_HH
#define MY_HEADER_HH

inline auto make_assign(int i) {return [i](int &x) {x=i;};}

#endif
```

wouldn't work if, say, multiple translation units tried to add various `make_assign(…)` objects to a `std::vector<decltype(make_assign(0))>`.